# Faint beep similar to HDD head skip (but it's not the HDD!) on Dell 7800

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, dell-precision

I'm pretty sure everybody here is familiar with the kind of beep hard disks make when waking up from DSM/hibernate and, often followed by an ominous click, when they're on their last leg. I heard it dozens of times.

It is heard after a long inactivity period after the HDD went to sleep, after the beep there is the slightest pause before everything starts working again etc... *that* beep.

So when I heard it coming from my brand new Dell 7800, after a brief annoyance I wasted no time in upgrading the secondary hard disk to a larger and faster SSHD. For, I think, six or seven months that was the end of it.

Then the beep made itself known again, and this time I took the plunge and replaced the SSHD disk with a Samsung SSD. This was last November. At the time I also pondered about the fact that the old Dell HDD was still alive, and after a 24-hours stress test with a live distro, I recycled it in an old laptop where it's still going strong. I began suspecting that the Dell mobo was maybe overstressing the hard disk mechanics.

The laptop has now a 256 GB primary SSD, and a 1TB secondary SSD. The tertiary and M.2 storage slots are empty, the optical storage bay is used by the DVDRW.

And you guessed it -- ten months later, *the beep is back*. Only, **this** time it cannot be the hard disk *since I no longer have any*.

- what can it be? It's not from the speakers, that's for sure.
- why did it go away for a while, both times, after replacing the HDD?

(I can think of one or two possible reasons involving a mechanical HDD, but none that allow for a solid state SSD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It was the power management.

I finally found [someone else who had the same problem](http://www.wadewegner.com/2007/03/how-to-stop-the-high-pitched-noise-emitted-by-dell-latitudes-updated/) and tracked it down to a power management issue in the Bluetooth driver.

Basically, if the Bluetooth module is shut down to save power, as soon as it powers on again it will emit a short sound mid-way between a buzz and a beep. Dell blames it on piezoelectricity. *Some* Dells do not exhibit this behavior, some do. It might require a specific combination of screw tightening to make the BT assembly resonate at the exactly right audio frequency.

However, **edit the BT Power Saving mode, set it to DISABLED (aka "Do not allow the computer to turn off this device to save energy"), and the problem is solved**.